# Using atom as text editor for Github for Windows

Tags: powershell, github

small question, I use atom text editor, today I installed Github for windows. Since all my commits messages triggered notepad.exe, I used the following line to change my global editor:

```
 git config --global core.editor atom
```

Now everytime I try to commit something, atom start and open the indicated file, but in my powershell windows, git says:

```
Aborting commit due to empty commit message.
```

There is any guide or config settings to make atom work with github for windows?  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I found a solution suggested by a person in the atom discussion forum:

```
 git config --global core.editor 'atom --wait'
```